# App Crashing After Selecting Picture From Gallery

Tags: java, android, xml, android-gallery

So whenever I select a picture from the gallery in  my app, it crashes. Here is the code for the button to the gallery and selected picture to the imageview.

```
pickImageButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onClick(View v) {
            openGallery();
         }
      });




}
private void openGallery() {                     //opens the gallery
      Intent gallery = 
         new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, 
         android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
      startActivityForResult(gallery, PICK_IMAGE);
   }
@Override
   protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
      super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
      if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == PICK_IMAGE) {
         Uri imageUri = data.getData();
         imageView2.setImageURI(imageUri);
      }
   }
```

Please comment if you need more information, I desperately need help, as this is a very major roadblock for me.

Comment: Does this help you help me? The whole log is way to long to post! 08-17 23:09:25.818: E/AndroidRuntime(1083): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=100, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=content://media/external/images/media/16 }} to activity {com.guruguru2.lostnfound/com.guruguru2.lostnfound.FoundMenu}: java.lang.NullPointerException

Answer (score 0):

Without the Logs, I can recommend on the following:

Make sure that **pickImageButton** isn't null.

Make sure that **imageView2** isn't null.

Make sure that in manifest your Activity is in:

```
android:launchMode="singleTop"
```